# How to parametrize a cubic plane curve

Tags: polynomials, plane-curves, rational-functions, parametrization

I've got a cubic surface, but I have no idea how to parametrize it.

If there is no general method, maybe there is one for a specific surface — z^2=x*y*(x+y-1).

I need to define this surface with the following equations: x=f1(u, v), y=f2(u, v), z=f3(u, v). The simpler f1, f2, f3 are, the better. Polynomials or rational functions will do for me.

Comment: Do you want to parametrise a curve? or a surface?

Comment: Your title says something different than your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $z^2\geq 0,$ the surface has $3$ sheets, one sheet with $x\geq 0,\;y\geq 0,\;x+y-1\geq 0$, one sheet with $x\leq 0,\; y\geq 0,\; x+y-1\leq 0$ and one sheet with $x\geq 0,\; y\leq 0,\; x+y-1\leq 0.$

For the first sheet, we can set 
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 &=&(1+v^2) u \\
y_1 &=&(1+v^2)(1-u) \\
z_1 &=& v\,(1+v^2)\, \sqrt{u(1-u)} 
\end{eqnarray}
with $u\in [0,1]$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}.$

The second sheet can be derived from the first one by setting
\begin{eqnarray}
x_2 &=& 1-x_1-y_1 \\
y_2 &=& x_1 \\
z_2 &=& z_1
\end{eqnarray}
because then we have
$$
x_2y_2(x_2+y_2-1) = (1-x_1-y_1)x_1(1-x_1-y_1+x_1-1) \\
= (1-x_1-y_1)x_1(-y_1) = x_1y_1(x_1+y_1-1)
$$
Analogously, we can set the following for the third sheet
\begin{eqnarray}
x_3 &=& y_1 \\
y_3 &=& 1-x_1-y_1  \\
z_3 &=& z_1
\end{eqnarray}
Rational solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
x_1 &=& \frac{(1+v^2) (1-u^2)^2}{(1+u^2)^2}  \\
\\
y_1 &=& \frac{(1+v^2) (2u)^2}{(1+u^2)^2}  \\
\\
z_1 &=& \frac{v\,(1+v^2)\, (1-u^2)(2u)}{(1+u^2)^2} 
\end{eqnarray}
with $u\in [0,1]$ and $v\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Thanks, Reinhard! That's what I was looking for. How did you come up with that parametrization? Is there any geometrical sense in "u" and "v"?

Comment: @iamcyrk The first step was to notice where (in terms of $x$ and $y$) the surface is defined. The lines $x=0,$ $y=0$ and $x+y-1=0$ separate the x-y-plane into $7$ areas, only $3$ of which can correspond to points in the surface. After I had seen this, I did not even try to find a common parameterization for all of the 3 sheets, but focused on the $x\geq 0,$ $y\geq 0,$ $x+y-1\geq 0$ case. Then I tried to get rid of the square roots by using trigonometric and hyperbolic functions (see history of my answer). To be continued ...

Comment: With a little bit of "try and error" I also managed to get rid of the transcendental functions, by accepting one single square root in the first parameterization. Then I verified if affine transformations would be sufficient to deal with the other sheets of the surface, luckily they did. As a last step, I used Pythagorean triples to get rid of the last remaining square root. All points $(x,y)$ with the same $u$ are on the same line through $(0,0).$ So you can think of $u$ as a parameter for the angle of that line and $v$ as a parameter for the distance from $(0,0).$

Comment: The last statements about the parameterization hold for the first sheet, only. The centers of the other sheets are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1).$

Comment: I am stunned by your skills and experience. Thanks for your comments. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, z is a function of x and y, so you can set f1 = u, f2 = v, and f3 = uv(u+v-1). There is no strategy for this in general, you just have to be creative.

Comment: I made a mistake in the surface equation. It should be z^2=x*y*(x+y-1) instead of z=x*y*(x+y-1).

Comment: I doubt there's anything nice we can do for this surface, especially because it has singularities. My best suggestion is to take the square root.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of an explicit relation $$z=f(x,y)$$ the parameterization is immediate:

$$z=f(x,y).$$

If you prefer,

$$\begin{cases}x=u,\\y=v,\\z=f(u,v).\end{cases}$$

Comment: I made a mistake in the surface equation. It should be z^2=x*y*(x+y-1) instead of z=x*y*(x+y-1).

Comment: @iamcyrk: take the square root.

Answer (score 0):

Monge's form with another individual parametrization:

$$ x= u+\frac12, y=v+\frac12, z= \pm \sqrt {(u+\frac12)(v+\frac12)(u+v)};$$